# Tealium: Fire JavaScript pixel on button click

Tags: tealium

I'm a new Tealium user and I have the following problem:

I have a JavaScript pixel that has to be implemented on a certain button click. I created a custom container tag and I added the Javascript code by editing the tag's template like this:

[image]

Apart of that I have this code that runs when I click the button:

[image]

So, I added this load rule to the tag:

[image]

The problem is that I don't see that the tag fires when I click the button.

Can you help me to find what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the link event data object is being set via a Tealium extension (but there is insufficient information in the question to be sure). If so, the scope and timing of that extension are critical for load rules processing. Make sure the variable `event_name` is getting set in an extension with a scope that allows execution before load rules. For a link event, this is typically “All Tags” scope and execution order is “Before Load Rules”.

Take a look at the Tealium extension docs for more information on Scope and Execution Order: https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/iQ-Tag-Management/Extensions/ta-p/13649#toc-hId-1361707577

Alternatively, make sure that your custom tag is coded properly and validate that it works correctly. It’s possible that you need to update the `u.ev` variable (defines which event types the tag can run on) and/or need to provide more instructions in the `u.loader_cb` callback statement: https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/iQ-Tag-Management/Tealium-Custom-Container-Tag/ta-p/14015

Debugging: https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/iQ-Tag-Management/Debugging/ta-p/30675